# What is Date? a string? or Double?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date

Okay, That might be asked somewhere, but I am unable to find it over google or SO,

My query was

```
INSERT INTO Tracking (OrderNum, PickupDate, ...) VALUES (95370,10/01/2013, .....)
```

plate form was a php script updating MS-Access db..and target column `pickupDate` was of Date/Time data type in access db..

when I ran this query, the information inserted in DB **wasn't** `10/01/2013`, rather its was long digit like 34444444299384 (something like that, didnt noted that exactly)..

but when I use the following query

```
INSERT INTO Tracking (OrderNum, PickupDate, ...) VALUES (95370,'10/01/2013', .....)
```

So for what I know is, **anything between the qoutes is a STRING**

- so, is the Date a string??
- why results are different for 10/01/2013 and `"10/01/2013"`?

Can somebody please explain it to me??

thanks for your guideline..

Comment: This question is tagged MySQL but you mention ms-access in your text.  What type of database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use:

```
10/01/2013
```

it is an expression: 10 divided by 1 divided by 2013, giving as a result: `0,0049677`... which is then converted to a date, as dates are really numbers.

When you use:

```
'10/01/2013'
```

It's a string, which is converted into a date.

Internally, a date is stored as a number, not a string.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that `10/01/2013` was interpreted as a division operation, so the resulting number was a small floating point number:

```
0.00496770988
```

From there, MySQL probably assumed you gave it a UNIX timestamp and it mangled the number to try to convert it into a storeable date.

What you want to do instead is give MySQL the format it prefers `YYYY-MM-DD` and quote it:

```
'2013-10-01'
```

[More on MySQL Dates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DATE` as the column type, your input is wrong.  MySQL expects `'2013-10-01'`, not `'10/01/2013'`.  See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: please see the input for your answer